# "BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash: invalid hash" with Omniauth Identity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth, bcrypt, bcrypt-ruby

I've a Rails 4 application with Omniauth Identity and on production I got some of this errors for some users(a few):

```
BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash: invalid hash
```

I've tested all the identity password_digest with the method hash_valid?

```
BCrypt::Password.valid_hash?(identity.password_digest)
```

And there are all good.

So I guess the problem come from the password given by the user but I've any idea where and I can't reproduce the error in development.

The form for log in is a basic one:

```
= form_tag "/auth/identity/callback?origin=#{request.original_url}", class: "simple_form" do
  .form-group.string
    = text_field_tag :auth_key, nil, class: "string form-control", placeholder: "Email", autofoucs: true
  .form-group.password
    %div
      = password_field_tag :password, nil,  placeholder: "Password"
  %p= submit_tag "Sign in"
```

Any Idea, thanks?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you have a blank password stored.

Be sure you are validating that your user enters a password.  If you trim whitespace, be sure you trim the password before making sure the string is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

BCrypt::Password.create('admin')

User this method

Answer (score 0):

I my case i stored the password using `Rails console` like below

```
user = User.find(2)
user.encrypted_password = "ilovepeace3"
user.save
```

and Just after that i encountered the error

> BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash: invalid hash

When i looked into users table I saw that password was saved just like I entered i.e in `plain text format` (`unencrypted`) . Then i did the following and Got rid of dirty error :P

```
 user = User.find_by_email(email)
 user.password     = params[:password]
 user.password_confirmation = params[:password_confirmation]
 user.save
```